# Finding a Function so that the Integral is Path Independent.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I need some help with an analysis problem I couldn't solve. 
Let $C$ be a smooth curve between two specific points. 
I need to find a function $H(x,y)$ such that the integral 
$$\int_C x^2 \sin{y}\,\mathrm{d}x + H(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}y$$ 
is path independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: a vector field $F=P\vec{i}+Q\vec{j}$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is conservative if  $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}$.

$F$ being conservative means that line integrals $\int_C F$ are independent of path. So, you should solve for $H(x,y)$ so that the above criterion is satisfied.

Comment: Thank you very much, 
Path independence => f = grad F.
∂F/∂x =x^2 * sin(y) => F(x,y) =(x^3)/x*sin(y) +g(y). 
∂F/∂y=Q(x,y) => F(x,y) = ∫ Q(x,y) dy.
∫ Q(x,y) dy = (x^3)/3 sin(y)+g(y)
=> Q(x,y) = (x^3)/3 cos(y) + dg/dy.
this is what I did, I don't know if it is right. And how can I find this g(y)?? Do I need it to be there at all??
And in the problem they specified the two points for me, do they have any usage for this question??